# Save text field to a variable using jQuery, showing undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to save the text field with the id #modelBox to a global variable so that it can be used later. However it seems no matter what I try the modelNumber is alerting 'undefined'. Any help is appreciated.

```
<input type = "textbox" value = "Enter Model Number" id="modelBox">

var modelBox="";
$('#modelBox').val('test');
var modelNumber = $('#modelBox').val();
alert(modelNumber);
var manufacturer = "unknown";
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit').click(function findManufacturer(){
  var firstFour = modelNumber.substring(0,4);
  if (firstFour.includes("B")){
    manufacturer = "AU Optronics";
    $('#answer').after("AU Optronics");
  }else{
     $('#answer').after("No Manufacturer found");
  }
  });
});
```

Comment: found no issue with above code. have you include jquery properly? check below my answer it works without any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this needs to be INSIDE your click handler so that you grab the value when you click. The way you have it, the val gets set on page load -- which is likely undefined at that point.

> var modelNumber = $('#modelBox').val();

```
$('#submit').click(function findManufacturer(){
    var modelNumber = $('#modelBox').val();
    var firstFour = modelNumber.substring(0,4);
    if (firstFour.includes("B")){
      manufacturer = "AU Optronics";
     $('#answer').after("AU Optronics");
   }else{
     $('#answer').after("No Manufacturer found");
    }
  });
 });
```

**EDIT:** You can also place it outside of the click handler, so long as it is inside the docready, and the field never changes between page load and clicking the submit button.

Comment: are you sure, in page load you cannot set and get value of an input field?

Comment: Depends. Does this output anything to console on load? alert(modelNumber); If so, then I am wrong about the handler. If not, there is your issue.

Comment: check below answer, i just copy and paste the same and it works absolutely fine!

Comment: Why does that work? Putting it inside the click handler worked. But shouldn't I be able to make this a global variable?

Comment: Because you need to be able to capture the final value entered into the textbox.

Also, var modelNumber = $('#modelBox').val(); run outside of the onReady means that it is going to try to grab the value of the field before page load is done - so it likely tries to grab the value before your global var is even set.

To be safe, always place your jQuery functions inside of your docready.

Technically you can move it out of the click handler - so long as it is inside the docready if the field value is not user definable.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code in below snippet, it alerts 'test'. Found no issue!

```js
var modelBox = "";
$('#modelBox').val('test');
var modelNumber = $('#modelBox').val();
alert(modelNumber);
var manufacturer = "unknown";
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').click(function findManufacturer() {
    var firstFour = modelNumber.substring(0, 4);
    if (firstFour.includes("B")) {
      manufacturer = "AU Optronics";
      $('#answer').after("AU Optronics");
    } else {
      $('#answer').after("No Manufacturer found");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="textbox" value="Enter Model Number" id="modelBox">
```

Comment: Interesting, works in the snippet but I am using an online IDE (codeanywhere) and I get an error when I run it. Putting it inside the click handler made it however.